# El nombre del objeto no es valido SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Instale SQL Server 2012 y SQL Server management studio.

Logré configurarlo y conectar a mi servidor local

A su vez, conseguí realizar un Restore de una base de datos utilizando el archivo .bak

El problema es que, cuando quiero hacer cualquier consulta (Por ejemplo un **Select ***) sobre esa BD, me muestra el mensaje en consola en color rojo:

**Mens. 208, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
El nombre de objeto 'GD2015C1' no es válido.**

Siendo GD2015C1 el nombre de mi base de datos.

Anduve buscando por StackOverflow (en español e ingles) y foros de microsoft pero no encuentro el error y literalmente no puedo hacer nada.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: El `select` no lo haces sobre una base de datos, sino sobre una o varias tablas, que pueden estar en una o varias bases de datos. `use MiBaseDeDatos; select * from MiTabla`, donde `MiBaseDeDatos` y `MiTabla` existan, no debiera dar problema.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que hay un problema al momento de escribir el código. Si se quiere incluir el nombre de la base de datos (cosa que no se recomienda a menos de que se llame desde otra base de datos) se hace con tres partes: NombreBD.NombreEsquema.NombreObjeto.

Es un error muy común cuando la gente no está acostumbrada al uso de esquemas, como los que trabajan con Oracle ya que ahí no existen.

En SQL Server, el esquema por default es dbo o el nombre de usuario.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de como se vería una consulta

```
SELECT * FROM GD2015C1.sys.objects;
SELECT * FROM GD2015C1.dbo.UnaTablaExistente;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que escribir en el script  `USE`  y el nombre de la base de datos que estás trabajando.

Un ejemplo así:

```
create database  DBAngular

use DBAngular

create TABLE Tarea(
idTarea int primary key identity,
nombre varchar(40)
)
insert into Tarea(nombre) values 
('Aprender Angular'),
('Aprender Blazor')

select * from  Tarea
```